# Facebook API email notification when a user post

Tags: email, facebook

I created a group on Facebook and I would like to know how I can send me an email when a user posts on the group wall.

I searched on Facebook API, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A cronjob, fetching posts and checking the new ones and then sending it to your email?

Comment: Yes why not but the facebook api doesn't provide something to do this ?

Comment: I agree 100% with you. It would be much easier.